# batch file - use dir /s /b %~dp0 to get list of files and remove %~dp0's path from output

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
ECHO ===FILES TO TRANSFER===
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%G IN (`DIR /B /S "%~dp0Files"`) DO @ECHO %%G
```

The output is the full path of the file/dir but I want to make it simpler by removing %~dp0's path from the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the methodology I'd suggest you incorporate, which protects filenames which may include `!` characters and limits the output to files, *as per your stated requirement*:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Dir /B/S/A-D "%~dp0Files" 2^>NUL')Do (
    Set "_=%%G" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo(!_:*%~dp0Files=.! & EndLocal)
Pause
```

If you'd prefer not to have a relative path type output then change `!_:*%~dp0Files=.!` to `!_:*%~dp0Files\=!`

---

Alternatively, you could grab the relative paths using the slower, `forfiles.exe` utility:

```batch-file
%__AppDir__%forfiles.exe /P "%~dp0Files" /S /C "%__AppDir__%cmd.exe /D/Q/C If @IsDir==FALSE Echo @RelPath"
```

If you prefer it without doublequotes then this modification should do that:

```batch-file
%__AppDir__%forfiles.exe /P "%~dp0Files" /S /C "%__AppDir__%cmd.exe /D/Q/C If @IsDir==FALSE For %%G In (@RelPath)Do Echo %%~G"
```

And if you wanted it without the leading `.\` then perhaps:

```batch-file
%__AppDir__%forfiles.exe /P "%~dp0Files" /S /C "%__AppDir__%cmd.exe /D/Q/C If @IsDir==FALSE For /F 0x22Tokens=1*Delims=\0x22 %%G In (@RelPath)Do Echo %%H"
```

You could also do this by leveraging `powershell.exe`:

```batch-file
%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile Get-ChildItem -Path "%~dp0Files" -File -Force -Name -Recurse
```

which could possibly be done, *(not recommended)*, in as short a line as:

```batch-file
powershell -NoP ls "%~dp0Files" -File -Fo -Na -Rec
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove `%~dp0` from each entry (Note: that doesn't work with `%%G` metavariables, you have to use a "normal" environment variable):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ECHO ===FILES TO TRANSFER===
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%G IN (`DIR /B /S "%~dp0"`) DO (
  set "file=%%G"
  echo !file:%~dp0=!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the relative path to a given root **without string manipulation**, you could use the [`xcopy` command](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) with its `/L` option, which lists relative paths to files it would copy without `/L`:

```cmd
pushd "%~dp0" && (
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%G in ('xcopy /L /S /Y /I "Files" "%TEMP%" ^| find "\"') do (
        echo(%%G
    )
    popd
)
```

[`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) are used to change into and return from the root directory, respectively.

The [`find` command](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) is used to suppress `xcopy`'s summary line `# File(s)`.